# GPO not applying at OU level

Tags: group-policy

I'm a new user here, and I've searched for this here.  I had an **Interactive logon: Message text for users attempting to log on** already working.  Then I changed the wording on the logon banner, and also the **Interactive logon: Message title for users attempting to log on** title to something else.  But after I did gpupdate /force and restarting, its still showing the old messages and title.  I did gpupdate /force at least 3 times, and also restarted computer, but its showing the old wording and title.

I have policy applied to an OU, and when I do gpresult /v this is what it shows.  Why is it doing that?  I'm new to this company, and all I did was change the wording and title for the interactive logon.

**The following GPOs were not applied because they were filtered out
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Local Group Policy
Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)
Local Group Policy
Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)**

Comment: I'm looking this post for guidance, and when I do gpresult /scope computer /z I can see the updated text on there, but then why isn't updated on the actual loon banner? 
 https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2225694-gpo-computer-settings-not-applying

Comment: `I have policy applied to an OU`. Which OU? What does `gpresult /h gpresult.html` show as the location where the current policy is applied from?

Comment: @GregAskew, sorry I'm just seeing your reply.  The logon banner is updated now.  For some reason that was applied to domain and OU level.  Once I updated it at the domain level, its showing the updated text.  So does this mean I can disable the interactive logon banner from the OU level?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, so just like it says in the other post, I had a domain level setting taking precedence over the OU level.  Now its showing updated text.

So I assume this means I can not enforce the GPO on the OU level or vice versa?  Meaning, I don't need the same thing on two locations.

Comment: That's the reason why enforcement exists, so it cannot be overridden at a lower level.

Comment: Thank you, so just to make sure (since I'm the only IT guy here at my company), I can disable the logon banner at the OU level?